# Coldbox routing dynamic number of path variables

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I am working on a coldbox application where I would like to create a route that accepts 'n' number of path variables as one variable. Here is what I mean.

```
http://localhost/api/variable1/variable2/variable3/...
```

I would like to either be able to grab everything after `/api` as one path variable where I can split on `/` and get the values or be able to iterate over all variables after `/api`.

Is there a way to setup a Route to do this?

```
with(pattern="/api", handler="api")
    .addRoute(pattern="/:variables", action="index")
.endWith();
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my response sufficiently answers your question, can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 5):

As you probably know, the default routing paradigm is to do name value pairs like so:

```
http://localhost/api/name1/value1/name2/value2/name3/value3
```

There is no need to create a custom route for that as everything after the matched part of the route is broken up into name/value pairs and placed in the rc automatically.

Now, it sounds like you're wanting to only have values in your route.  If you know the *maximum* number of variables you'll ever have, you could create a route of optional, incrementally-named variables.

```
addRoute(pattern="/:var1?/:var2?/:var3?/:var4?/:var5?", action="index")
```

Now, if you truly might have an unlimited number of variables, there is no way to do a route that will match that.  What you CAN do is have your route match the /api bit and write an onRequestCapture interceptor that grabs the URL and does your **own** custom parsing on it.  Note, you may need to remove the name/value pairs that ColdBox will try to put in the rc.

I will add a note of caution-- the only way for this to really work is for you to KNOW the order of the incoming variables ahead of time, and if you know that, there is no reason why you can't create a known route for it.  Otherwise you're basically rebuilding the SES interceptor over again which is an anti-pattern called "inner platform effect"

http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/URLMappings.cfm#URL_Mappings

http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Interceptors.cfm#Core_Interception_Points

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect